# jQuery attribute selector not working with multiple words

Tags: jquery

For example I have the following element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="propertyValue" value="This and That">
```

And calling the following:

```
 $("a.my-class-name").click(function(event) {
   var value = $(this).attr('data-ref');
   $('input[type="hidden"][value=' + value + ']').remove();
 });
```

I verified the variable value is passing the correct value (in this case "This and That"). Also verified it is working when value is not multiple words. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the value as string. Use following script.

```
$("a.my-class-name").click(function (event) {
                var value = $(this).attr('data-ref');
                $('input[type="hidden"][value="' + value + '"]').remove();
            });
```

Put "" around value will do the trick. 
Here is a working JSFIDDLE.

https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/kyxupucd/2/

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing! Working now.

Comment: Happy to help :) @OtoNoOto